# input tag : onclick doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

When I click on submit button(acquista) the javascript code doesn't works.Why?
The function conferma is not called.How can I solve it? This is part of the code of my jsp page.Thanks and sorry for my english

payment.jsp

```
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/conferma.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
     ....

 <form action="acquista" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dati Pagamento</legend>
                <table id="dati_carta">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Numero Carta</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="numero_carta" required="required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><img src="resources/images/payment.gif" width="200" height="30"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Titolare Carta</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="titolare_carta" required="required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><label>mm</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label>yy</label></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Scadenza</label></td>
                        <td><input id="mese_carta" type="text" name="mese_carta" required="required"/>
                        <label>/</label>
                        <input id="anno_carta" type="text" name="anno_carta" required="required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>CVC</label></td>
                        <td><input id="cvc" type="password" name="cvc" required="required"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            <br/>
            <table id="tabella_button">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="reset" class="reset_button" value="Annulla"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="acquista_button" value="Acquista" onclick="return conferma('Procedere con l'acquisto?');"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        ....
 </body>
```

conferma.js

```
function conferma(msg) {
var x=msg;
if (confirm(msg))return true;
 else return false;
}//conferma
```

Comment: The negative votes are most likely due to the fact that you posted a question involving a typo which could have easily been found by simply taking a look at the console. Try pressing F12.

Comment: but I could not find the error and so I write a new question.Please remove the negative votes.

Comment: Did you look at the console? If you are confused by the console message and can't figure out what it means, fine, post that as a question, but you should not post code which generates console errors without looking at them yourself first. SO is not a free typo-spotting service. Your browser and its devtools are MUCH better (and faster) at spotting typos.

Comment: I thought that the function java script was wrong, or that there was some other error

Comment: OK, one more time. Did you look at the console, yes or no? What did it say?

Comment: The console says nothing, for this I wrote this question..

Comment: In Eclipse I haven't red and black color , but instead I have always blue color

Comment: When I load this page, and press the submit button, the console DOES display a perfectly helpful error message, in the case of Chrome it is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", even giving the line number.

Comment: I'm a student and I don't know these things

Comment: In Firefox console I have : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Right, the specific error will differ from browser to browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
'Procedere con l'acquisto?'
```

You can't use `'` characters in a string delimited by `'` characters without escaping them.

```
\'
```

You should have got an error message about this in your JS error console.

Comment: In Firefox console I have : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list